# Using only AAAA record for a domain?

Tags: ip, ipv6, domain

Can I point a domain to IPv6 only, instead of IPv4 and will it be fully functional? I've searched for a tip on the Internet, but I've found only for using both.

Comment: I actually do this for individual systems in my dual-stack network. In theory, if I'm at someplace with ipv6, I can use hostname.domainame.tld to access specific systems in my network. This would depend on your values of fully functional tho

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If there's no A record, then IPv4-only clients will not be able to reach it.

Aside from that, there is no rule requiring a specific address type. You can have AAAA-only domains exactly the same way as you can have A-only domains.

Answer (score 11):

Having only a AAAA record and no A record for your domain makes it available to those 5% of the users, who currently have IPv6 access. The remaining 95% of the users won't be able to access your content unless they are prepared to jump through hoops to get at it.

I got those numbers from [Google](https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html). Using a logistic growth model on the [raw numbers](https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/ipv6/statistics/data/adoption.js) suggest that the number will reach 50% about three years from now. Until then you have to consider whether it is acceptable to make your content unavailable to more than half the potential users.

If making your content easily available to as many users as possible is important to you then create both A and AAAA records.

If you feel that pushing IPv6 is more important to you than making this content easily available, then you can configure your domain with only AAAA records. Only a minority of content publishers will want to take that approach.

Disclaimer: I am operating [a service](http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/) intended at making it feasible for individuals to publish content on IPv6 only servers and still reach IPv4 only users.